# escaping $ sign for String.replace

Tags: javascript, regex

At following String.replace line, lossLocation.state$ ,

the $ sign is removed after the replace,

i need to keep the $, as it is used in the variable.

```
 '{0}'.replace(
         '{0}'
       , 'categories.Country === \'$formData.lossLocation.state$\'.toUpperCase()')
```

It gives me

```
"categories.Country === '$formData.lossLocation.state'.toUpperCase()"
```

The expected outcome should be

```
"categories.Country === '$formData.lossLocation.state$'.toUpperCase()"
```

i've tried the following but still been removed when replace

```
state\$
```

Comment: Ya, seems like related issue. probably close it after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it states in [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). To escape '$' in replacement content, you should use '$$' instead of '\$'.

So a proper way of constructing it would be

```
'{0}'.replace('{0}', 
    'categories.Country === \'$formData.lossLocation.state$\'.toUpperCase()'
        .replace(/\$/g, '$$$$')
)
```